# NLP Lemmatization with Wordnet: Error [E1041] Expected a string, Doc, or bytes as input, but got: <class 'NoneType'>

Tags: python, error-handling, nlp, wordnet, lemmatization

I have defined the 'pre_processing' function as follows:

```
import nltk
import unicodedata
from nltk.tokenize import TweetTokenizer
from nltk.corpus import wordnet
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from spellchecker import SpellChecker

# Tokenisation
tokenizer = TweetTokenizer() # Initialise an object of the TweetTokenizer class

# Lemmatization
nltk.download('wordnet') # Download lemmatizers from NLTK
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer() # Initialise an object of the WordNetLemmatizer class 

# Stopwords 
nltk.download('stopwords') # Downloand stopwords from NLTK

# Spellchecker
spell_check = SpellChecker() # Initialise an object of the SpellChecker class

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm") # Load package "en_core_web_sm" from spacy

def pre_process(character_text):
    """Pre-process all the concatenated lines of a character, 
    using tokenization, spelling normalization and other techniques.

    ::character_text:: a string with all of one character's lines
    """

    initial_tokens = tokenizer.tokenize(character_text) # Tokenization with TweetTokenizer
    pos_tagged = nltk.pos_tag(initial_tokens) # Part of speech tagger to tag the list of tokens

    stop_words = set(stopwords.words("english")) # Initialise a set that stores common english     stopwords

    punc_cat = set(["Pc", "Pd", "Ps", "Pe", "Pi", "Pf", "Po"]) # Check punctuation in tokens
    # Taken from the NLTK's module for POS tagging using CRFSuite official documentation

    tokens = []
           
    for token, tag in pos_tagged:
        if token == "_EOL_": # If end of sentence 
             tokens.append(token)
            
        if unicodedata.category(token[0]) not in punc_cat: # If a token is not a punctuation letter
        # The unicodedata.category method returns the general category assigned to the character as a string
        
            misspelled = spell_check.unknown(token) # Check and correct mispelled words 
            if len(misspelled)!= 0:
                token = spell_check.correction(token)

            if token not in stop_words: # If a token is not a stopword
                # Check for the common word POS-taggers
                if tag[0] == 'V':
                    tag_type = wordnet.VERB
                elif tag[0] == 'J':
                    tag_type = wordnet.ADJ
                elif tag[0] == 'N':
                    tag_type = wordnet.NOUN
                elif tag[0] == 'R':
                    tag_type = wordnet.ADV
                else:
                    tag_type = None
            
                if tag_type is not None:  
                    token = lemmatizer.lemmatize(token, tag_type) # Lemmatization with Wordnet 
                
                tokens.append(token)
                
    return tokens
```

Then, when I run the following lines:

```
# create list of pairs of (character name, pre-processed character) 
training_corpus = [(name, pre_process(doc)) for name, doc in sorted(train_character_docs.items())]
train_labels = [name for name, doc in training_corpus]
```

I get this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3cc88.png)

I understand what the error means. But it is strange that I get this error taking into account the fact that I have specified the following line before lemmatizing:

```
if tag_type is not None:
```

So, I have tried the simplest way to get rid of this 'None' values by dropping all the rows with Nan values in the original dataset. But it did not help. I suppose it is the naive way and I need to get deeper into the error.

I then looked into similar Error questions on stackoverflow, naively tried out applying all the solutions, but it did not help.